# Decode JSON with python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read data from an arduino via serial which sends a JSON string with the name and values of 6 sensors.

I have checked the string in a JSON validator to be valid. The problem is that I receive an error while attempting to get the dictionary from JSON string.

```
import json
import serial
import Sensor
s = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
while True:
    m = s.readline()
    x = m.decode('UTF-8').rstrip("\n")
    b = json.loads(x)
    print(b['list'])

{"list":[{"name":"A0","value":"17"},{"name":"A1","value":"39"},
{"name":"A2","value":"13"},{"name":"A3","value":"48"},
{"name":"A4","value":"10"},{"name":"A5","value":"42"}]}
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/andrei_vlad/PycharmProjects/untitled/serial_comm.py", line 9, in <module>
    b = json.loads(x)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Update:
I solved the problem. Decode was adding '' before and after the string. I just used x[1:-1] and it works now. Also i had another string which was sent in readline to notify that the connection started.

Comment: Dropping the json string you posted in `json.loads` works fine here...

Comment: You probably end up with broken data while doing `readline`, seeing as you manage to get one `print(b['list'])` out, `readline` probably returns a empty string or something. do  `print([m])` before `m.decode` and check the actual value/data returned from your serial connection.

Comment: This is the value returned, i removed any values from value so it's not an error  if it's empty  :  [b'{"list":[{"name":"A0","value":""},{"name":"A1","value":""},{"name":"A2","value":""},{"name":"A3","value":""},{"name":"A4","value":""},{"name":"A5","value":""}]}\r\n']

Comment: When people ask for additional information, it's better to update your question (because you can format the information to make it more readable than in a comment).

Comment: I solved the problem. Decode was adding '  ' before and after the string. I just used x[1:-1] and it works now. Also i had another string which was sent in readline to notify that the connection started. Thanks for tip larsks, I'am new here :).

Comment: It is also a good idea to post your solution to your own question if you find it on your own (not in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Decode adds "  ' " at the start and the end of the string so I had to remove these two characters using `x = x[1:-1]`
Solution:

```
import json
import serial
import Sensor
s = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
m = s.readline()
print([m])
x =m.decode().strip('\n\r')
x = x[1:-1]
x = json.loads(x)
print(x['list'])
```